# Firefox - open pinned tab from terminal

Tags: bash, firefox, terminal

I use Firefox nightly on Ubuntu 16.04. I have a bunch of websites I keep open throughout the day as pinned tabs. In an effort to automate things I have a bash alias which opens them up for. However, I cannot find a way to open those as pinned tabs with firefox.

Is there any way I can open a website in firefox in a pinned tab via terminal?

Comment: One of the opening options is to start with the tabs open during the last session.  With that, you just need to open Firefox.  Is that close enough?

Comment: @fixer1234 No, I don't always want to keep those sites open, for example on weekends.

Comment: Can't you differentiate this with profiles?  If a tab is pinned, it's there when you open Firefox, without doing anything special.  If there are times you don't want it open, use a separate profile.